# MySQL Sum total using Group By multiple columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

The following query:

```
SELECT `brand`,
       count(*) * `denomination` AS 'total'
FROM `inventory`
WHERE `owner` = 'owner-one'
    AND `currency` = 'GBP'
    AND `activated_at` IS NULL
    AND `expires_at` >= '2018-06-21'
GROUP BY `owner`,
         `brand`,
         `currency`,
         `denomination`
```

Produces:

```
| brand     | total |
|-----------|-------|
| brand-one | 3000  |
| brand-one | 8000  |
| brand-two | 10000 |
```

What I'd like is to further group by the item and sum the totals so the output is like:

```
| brand     | total |
|-----------|-------|
| brand-one | 11000 |
| brand-two | 10000 |
```

The data:

[image: Sample data]

Comment: can you please show the source for the example

Comment: For the longest time I couldn't figure out were the 1100 was coming from.   then it dawned on me that I think you mean 11000  I would think group by grouping sets or maybe rollup may do what you're after.

Comment: Ahh crap, bloody typo. Yes, 11000.

Comment: So why do you get three records now.. I see group by denomination.... Why count(*)*denomination? why don't you just sum(denomination) and remove denomination from the group by? also confused by further group by the item... by item do you mean the owner/brand/currency? or is there an actual item code on each of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get 3 records is that the group by contains denomination.  If we change the logic so that we sum instead of count(*) * denomination then we can get the two records your after. (provided  you remove denomination from the group by)...  but maybe i'm missing something.

```
SELECT `brand`,
       Sum(`denomination`) AS 'total'
FROM `inventory`
WHERE `owner` = 'owner-one'
  AND `currency` = 'GBP'
  AND `activated_at` IS NULL
  AND `expires_at` >= '2018-06-21'
GROUP BY `owner`,
         `brand`,
         `currency`
```